# Is more than one form tag a bad idea?

Tags: html, forms

I had made a simple project on some person records, where I have to make a login page,
and after that other things like add, delete, update operation and all. I have made,
2 to 3 form tag in a JSP. When my senior comes to review my code, he said, using more form
tag is a bad idea. But I didn't get why and neither he told me. So please anyone can
explain that. Specially what are the harms it may create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsically wrong with using multiple forms in a single document.

It might be that, in your specific case, it would make more sense to use a single form to reduce duplication, but we can't say for sure as we don't know the specifics of what you did.

Comment: Well, I have divided the form tags for user's information edit, and user's address edit. So I have made different servlet for both of them

Comment: So the user can't update their address and their other information in one go? That sounds like poor interaction design.

Comment: then what should i do?I do not have to use struts any kinda framework for that.

Comment: Letting them update all the information with one form and one HTTP request sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, nothing wrong with them from an HTML perspective, and there are quite a few examples out there on how to do it:

[JSP With Multiple Forms](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jsp_with_multiple_forms.shtml)

[Using Multiple Forms](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/simple-jsp-example/UsingMultipleForms.shtml)

In ASP.NET there is a potential problem in ASP.NET, which will only allow you to have one server-side form tag (with runat:server as attribute). Not sure if something similar/equivalent would hold for JSP.